# Linkedin API for Company page insights stats?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have read through linkedin api docs on the site, but I have not been able to find any proper apis for company page's stats such as 'impressions' and 'engagement' provided in linkedin company page.
Only that I could find as a stats was 'num-followers' using company API.

Anyone knows the way of extraction of the linkedin stat data ??

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260355/linkedin-api-get-insights-clicks-interactions-engagement-for-company-update)