# Linkedin API: Get insights (clicks, interactions, engagement) for company updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to extract stat information for updates (posts) of company pages. I have succeeded in getting:

- likes and comments
- daily/monthly impressions

but I can't seem to find where I can get: clicks, interactions and engagement.

Does anyone know if this information is available through the API or the partnership programs?

Edit: The question was originally asked for LinkedIn API v1 for which the documentation is lacking. For V2, the answer lives here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics

Comment: the links are broken, maybe they can be updated to the new api v2 for people arriving at this page looking for help more recently?

Comment: This applies only for organization pages? You can't use same for your personal posts. I mean you can't get number of impressions for your personal post?

Comment: @AndriySambir did you find a way to get the number of impressions for personal posts? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Query should be like

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3502837/historical-status-update-statistics:(time,like-count,impression-count,click-count)?time-granularity=month&start-timestamp=1388514600000&end-timestamp=1433097000000&format=json

After URL, before query params :(time,like-count,impression-count,click-count)

Answer (score 1):

The question was originally asked for LinkedIn v1 APIs.

For v2, the answer is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics